# Invisible reCAPTCHA integration with angular component

Tags: angular, recaptcha

I want to integrate invisible recaptcha in angular 2 component.

Here is my code in login.component.html

```
 <button type="submit" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<Site-Key>" data-callback='onsubmit'> Log On </button>
```

And the login.component.ts has onsubmit method as below:

```
     onsubmit() {
  console.log("In onsubmit method");
}
```

I am getting the following error when i call onsubmit method from my login.component.ts

```
ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function:onsubmit
```

and how to get the 'g-recaptcha-response' in my login.component.ts.

Comment: I would like to know how to do this as well. Using the package is fine but adds more weight to the application.

Answer (score 1):

reCaptcha Callback can not find your onsubmit function because **its a Method** in your component.

you can **attach your global function to the window object** like this :

```
window['onsubmit'] = () => {
    ...
}
```

you can do this in the constructor of your Component

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins that can helps you integrating google recaptcha with angular such as angular-recaptcha (more details here https://github.com/VividCortex/angular-recaptcha)

We are using it to validate forms and it works fine.

Comment: is it invisible?

Comment: Yes it is invisible recaptcha.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it by using [ng-recaptcha3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-recaptcha3) plugin. It is google reCAPTCHA 3 implementation for angular 2+.

Init

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private recaptcha3: NgRecaptcha3Service) {
  this.recaptcha3.init(YOUR_SITE_KEY)

  }
```

And then before login, execute recaptcha

```
  onSubmit() { 
    // generate new token
    this.recaptcha3.getToken().then(token => {
      const formData = this.myForm.value;
      formData.recaptchaToken = token;
      // send data with token to backend
      this.http.post(url,formData) ....
 
    }
 
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-recaptcha3)